Deciphering a banderole in Master Francke's "Nativity"
What is the text coming from Mary's mouth in this altarpiece by Master Francke? According to one source I found, the text says Dominus meus, Deus meus (my Lord, my God). But the third word in the banderole does not look like Deus to me. So what is it?


Its 'et deus' with a gothic ligatur  for 'et'.  It's a common heraldic motto from John (20, verse 28). see eg https://www.heraldry-wiki.com/wiki/Co-Cathedral_Basilica_of_St._Thomas_the_Apostle,_Ortona

I see, so it's using the ligature here? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%81%8A

@RolandF You should go ahead and make that the answer.
